# How can I get the center of a polygon using Google Maps?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

In my project, I have an array of `CLLocationCoordinate2D` which I need to find the center point of. In the Android google maps sdk, there is a nifty function that calculates the center...

```
LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
builder.include(listOfBounds);
LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();

centerLatLng = bounds.getCenter();
```

Is there a function equivalent to this that can calculate the center point included in the ios sdk, or will I have to write my own function?

Comment: maybe this helps: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/164267/how-exactly-is-the-centroid-of-polygons-calculated

Comment: sadly, there is no center property for GMSCoordinateBounds. I submitted a feature request for it.

Answer (score -1):

If your bounds are a CGRect, it's easy to get the center using `rect.midx` and `rect.midy`.  If your LatLngBounds are GMSCoordinateBounds, then get the midpoints by

```
let centerLatitude = bounds.northEast.latitude + bounds.southWest.latitude
let centerLongitude = bounds.southWest.longitude + bounds.northEast.longitude
```

I don't know of a center function in the iOS SDK.